# How to deduplicate streaming query with arbitrary stateful processing in Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am performing [arbitrary stateful stream processing](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) using Spark. The use case involves identifying user session (based on a specific ID, say *session_id*, so all user activity events for 1 session will have the same *session_id*), tracking the progress of the session(inprogress or completed), etc. Also, my use case involves identifying **duplicate sessions** based on some fields (which do not include the ID, so session_id for **duplicate sessions** is different).

Now, I am using Spark Structured Streaming's flatMapGroupsWithState using *session_id* as the grouping_key for my processing. 
But I am unable to figure out how to identify duplicates and perform deduplication, since it involves different fields than the one used to identify a session. I would consider the later attempt to be valid and consider the older one to be duplicate.

Comment: A quick answer would be to create a mega-id to include the session id and the other fields that could make sessions duplicates. That seems to give Spark enough information about what could be considered duplicates.

Comment: Why don't you use `Dataset.dropDuplicates` (or at least try to as I think that would give you a sense of what's required to have a mega-id)?

Comment: As far I know, dropDuplicates will drop the later entries but I want to keep the later ones.

Comment: Also, sessionisation is done by an ID which is different from the ID used to identify duplicates. The use case is to identify duplicate attempts at some activity (called sessions), and those sessions are guaranteed to have different session ID(since they are different attempts) but some other ID (say, ip + user_id combo) is same. If I receive a session (in, say 30 minutes) which has the same ip + user_id as an older session, I want to mark the older one as duplicate. Even if I do not drop the older session, just marking one would be good enough.